# 5 digit url in google search breadcrum

Tags: sitecore-client, seo

On Searching anything on google chrome regarding my sitecore website then it showed 5 digit language code in search page breadcrums[image: en-us] in the US region, not able to replicate in indian region can it be resolved anyhow? we only want two digit url

Comment: You can set 'languageEmbedding' to'Never' in LinkManager. https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/02/disable-language-code-embedding-in-urls.html

Comment: would it be removing the whole language code? We need 2 digit language code

Comment: yes it will remove whole. I suspect, you will  need some customization in LinkManager to change that code. Do check my answer below, you may need to shift your focus to sitemap fist.

Comment: I have written code to customize language in URL, but I want to remove those pages which already present in google indexing

Answer (score 0):

Search Engine crawls website urls through Sitemap. You can check if you have embedded language in US region site. If yes, you need to get rid of that. Once you update it, you can notify google about change in sitemap manually through this url,

http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap-file.xml

You can find how it works for other search engines, else you will have to be patient since search engines have already crawled urls of your site. It will update gradually.

And, at last, you can get rid of language code from urls by setting 'languageEmbedding' to'Never' in LinkManager.

[Change Language Embedding](https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/02/disable-language-code-embedding-in-urls.html)

Comment: There are only 2 digit language code in sitemap

Comment: Then I assume this is just re-indexing your new sitemap. You can try above url to let Google know about you sitemap changes. I am not sure, how much time would that take to reflect though.